# flutter Table similar to shown image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-table, flutter-datatable

I am new to Flutter. I have tried majority of data table structure but unable to create this functionality.

How to create similar table structure as shown in image with dynamic data?

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this package: https://pub.dev/packages/data_table_2

It almost looks exactly like what you provided and I am sure you can customize it further.